# Autocompletion on touchscreen device without JQuery

Tags: firefox, autocomplete, prototype, touchscreen, motorola

Is there a way to use Prototype on a touchable mobile device for the autocompletion? The observer will only be activated if I type smth like ":" or ";" but if I type numbers or letters, nothing happens. After typing a colon or semicolon, also some letters and numbers will be recognized but only three or four whichafter I have to type a colon again. I am usin "Android 4.4" and "Firefox 35".

Comment: Otsustasin, et kuna kaks päeva juba uuritud, kuidas lahendada ja pole toimiva tavalise isetäitmise lahenduseni jõudnud, siis lahendan asja nii:
1 Inimene trükib kasti mingi osa sõnest nagu seni või terve sõne.
2 Kui sõne on osaline, vajutab kasti juures olevale otsimisnupule.
3 Teostatakse AJAX-päring ja saadakse tulemused vastavalt osalisele otsisõnele.
4 Kui tulemusi on üks, täidetakse kohe kast, kui rohkem, tekitatakse kasti alla nupud iga tulemusega.

Comment: 5 Tulemusenupule vajutamine kaotab tulemusnupud ja kast täidetakse.

See lahendus peaks ka kasutamise nutitelefonis mugavamaks muutma, sest kasutaja võib ka sõrmistikku kasutamata saada nimekirja ning siis nihutab ainult, mitte ei pea ootama, kuni lõpuks virtuaalne klaviatuur kuvale manatakse ja siis seal väikeseid klahve taga ajama, vaid saab kasutada suuri nuppe.